# Angular 2 module loading and imports

Tags: angular, systemjs

I have an Angular 2 app made using Quickstart from angular.io and I am using SystemJs for module loading (see [QuickStart guide](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)) and I have the following questions:

1. `import { Component} from '@angular/core';`
   What is this statement doing? Is it loading the @angular/core or is it just loading Component from @angular/core?
   How is @angular/core loaded here since I have not included script tag that loads angular in any way?
2. What is the use of systemJs in Angular 2?
3. How is my es6 code transpiling to es5?
4. Is systemJs also doing bundling of all the js files here? Or each angular module is loading through ajax?

Comment: What do you mean by 3. I assume you don't want a full explanation how translating from one language into another is working.

Comment: No. not the complete explanation. Just how is it happening in quickstart? Through systemjs or any other library? Is it happening automatically or I will have to transpile it explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a look at the javascript that gets transpiled from the typescript?

1. import { Component} from '@angular/core';

Does two things: Transpiles into a require call if you have commonjs as module format in typescript, e.g.

```
var core_1 = require('@angular/core');

core_1.Component({})
```

Second it tells the compiler to look for the types of class Component in @angular/core. By default all non relative paths in import are looked up in the node_modules folders. So it would look at:

node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts for @angular/core

2. SystemJs is used as module loader at runtime. The browser sees in production only the transpiled javascript. So it has to know, where to look for the dependencies, this is defined in systemjs.config.js.

There the packages for @angular/core are defined to look in node_modules by default. Here you can also define to load the dependencies from a CDN, and the version in node_modules would only be used for compilation of the Typescript to Javascript.

3. Typescript compiler does the conversion from ES6 to ES5. See typescript config: tsconfig.json
4. SystemJs is not doing the bundling, it can actually load bundles. Bundling of your javascript needs to be done in continuous integration, e.g. through grunt or gulp.

Answer (score 0):

1. This isn't actually doing much. It just makes `Component` known in the current file and points to where `Component` is declared.

Answer (score 0):

1 : from the file path `@angular/core` : It is importing the Component class into the current file

2: System js is a module loader it loads all javascript modules more of bundling them

If You checked the dependencies of angular2 in `package.json` file 
You will find the `@angular/core` path as a dependency. So within @angular/core the Component class is defined :

The statement `import {Component} from  @angular/core` says:  follow the path to `@angular/core` and make the `Component` class available to the current file

Comment: How is it loading @angular/core to find its path to import Componenet?